# Org mode link to vlc video with start time in minutes:seconds and possible duration

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I am beginning to struggle with organizing my videos. I have screen recordings of conversations with my product owner and would like to have convenient links in my org files that would start the video at the right spot.

At the moment I use min_sec script that converts the position of 02:25 to its value in seconds and passes it to a script that starts the video at the right spot.

```
#+begin_example
vlc ~/Videos/simplescreenrecorder-2023-05-15_14.55.22.mkv --start-time=`min_sec 2 25`
# or with stop time
vlc ~/Videos/simplescreenrecorder-2023-05-15_14.55.22.mkv --start-time=`min_sec 2 09` --stop-time=`min_sec 5 50`

#+end_example
```

Is there a way to do it in Emacs?

Comment: I *think* this might help: The link subsystem in Org mode is extensible: you can define your own link types with whatever behavior you want (within the bounds of the extension mechanism). See the variable `org-link-parameters` and the function `org-link-set-paramers`. You can find a number of examples in the Org mode sources by `grep`-ing for `org-link-set-parameters`.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but you can associate extensions with applications using `org-file-apps`. So that you can open a file in a specific application from an `org-link`. Example: https://dpaste.org/zOwLG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution:
https://github.com/bigos/prelude/blob/master/modules/org-vlc.el

```
;;; org-vlc.el --- a simple package                     -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;; Copyright (C) 2023 Jacek Podkanski

;; Author: Jacek Podkanski
;; Keywords: lisp
;; Version: 0.0.1

;; This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
;; it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
;; the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
;; (at your option) any later version.

;; This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;; but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;; MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;; GNU General Public License for more details.

;; You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;; along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

;;; Commentary:

;; Org-vlc provides links for org mode file that allow to use vlc to open video
;; files with the optional start time and stop time.

;;; Code:

;; code goes here
(require 'org)

;;; correct way of adding links
;; https://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-Hyperlink-Types.html


;; https://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-Hyperlink-Types.html
(org-link-set-parameters "vlc"
                         :follow #'org-vlc-open)

(defun org-vlc--my-time-to-seconds (time)
  "Convert TIME in minutes and seconds as 01:20 to seconds as 80."
  (let ((time-parts (mapcar #'string-to-number
                            (split-string time ":"))))
    (if (eq 3 (length time-parts))      ; hrs min sec
        (+ (* 3600 (car time-parts))
           (* 60 (cadr time-parts))
           (caddr time-parts))
      (+ (* 60 (car time-parts))        ; naiive min sec
         (cadr time-parts)))))

(defun org-vlc--time-option (option fn split-timings)
  (let ((time-part (apply fn (list  split-timings))))
    (when time-part
      (format option (org-vlc--my-time-to-seconds time-part)))))

(defun org-vlc-open (link)
  "Where page number is 105, the link should look like:
   [[vlc:/path/to/file.mp4#01:05][My description.]]
   or
   [[vlc:/path/to/file.mp4#01:05-03:25][My description.]]"
  (let* ((path+timing (split-string link "#"))
         (afile (car
                 (split-string
                  (car path+timing)
                  ":")))
         ;; time options
         (timings (cadr path+timing))
         (split-timings (when timings (split-string timings "-")))
         (start-at
          (org-vlc--time-option "--start-time=%s" #'car split-timings))
         (end-at
          (org-vlc--time-option "--stop-time=%s" #'cadr split-timings)))

    ;; (message "vlc opening video %s at  %s %s %s" afile timings start-at end-at )
    (let ((options
           (cond ((and (null start-at) (null end-at))
                  (list  "view-vlc" nil "vlc" afile))
                 ((and start-at (null end-at))
                  (list  "view-vlc" nil "vlc" afile start-at))
                 ((and start-at end-at)
                  (list  "view-vlc" nil "vlc" afile start-at end-at))
                 (t (merssage "error in time arguments")))))
      (message "starting vlc %S" options)
      (apply #'start-process options))))

(provide 'org-vlc)
;;; org-vlc.el ends here
```

Comment: Why have a `let*` inside a `let`? A single `let*` would do, I think.

Comment: And I would move it all to its own file and just `require` it from the init file. You'll also need to worry about loading it at the appropriate time (e.g. after loading `ol`).

Comment: https://github.com/bigos/prelude/blob/d46d3a9bc4f621c3dd3de43a226424d32e9de817/modules/org-vlc.el#L30

Comment: You should add/replace the code in your answer above with the code from the link, or add the link to your question - don't leave essential information to comments. It is preferable for the answer to be self-contained, not depending on external links but that's a gray area.

Comment: done, I have put the link and code in the answer

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: And BTW, you can accept your own answer...